# How to factor a polynomial quickly in $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

I was doing an exercise in Brzezinski's *Galois Theory Through Exercises* and needed to factor the polynomial
$x^6+5x^2+x+1=x^6+x+1$ in $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$. Is there a quick way to do this?

I can see it has no roots and therefore no linear factors, so it must either factor as the product of a quadratic and a quartic or two cubics, but listing the irreducible quadratics and cubics mod $5$ is laborious. I found all of the irreducible quadratics, which are \begin{multline} 
x^2\pm 2, \, x^2+x+1, \, x^2+x+2, \, x^2+2x-2, \, x^2+2x-1, \\ 
x^2-2x+2, \, x^2-2x-2, \, x^2-x+1, x^2-x+2
\end{multline}
and checked that none of these are factors, so it must factor as the product of two cubics, which I know I could find either by finding all irreducible cubics or by writing
$$
x^6+x+1 = (x^3+ax^2+bx+c)(x^3+dx^2+ex+f) 
$$
and then equating coefficients.

I used a computer to perform the Berlekamp algorithm which yielded the factorisation
$$
x^6+5x^2+x+1 = (x^3-2x^2-1)(x^3+2x^2-x-1)
$$
but it would take me a very long time to do this by hand. Can anyone suggest any tricks that could be applied here?

Comment: It is not so difficult to compute the irreducible cubic polynomials over $\Bbb F_5$ by hand (because you only need to find a root or see that there is none). Then you can easily multiply those to see if you can get $x^6+5x^2+x+1$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks for your comment. Aren't there rather a lot of irreducible monic cubics over $\mathbb{F}_5$? If I write the polynomial as $x^3+ax^2+bx+c$, $c\neq0$, there are $5\cdot5\cdot4=100$ possibilities to check.

Comment: There are $p(p-1)$ monic irreducible cubics over $\Bbb F_p$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3280530/number-of-irreducible-monic-polynomials-of-degree-3-over-bbb-f-p-p-prime?noredirect=1&lq=1). So yes, we have $20$ of them for $p=5$, but they are already known. So you don't have to work for it. Finally, why not use a computer? Berlekamp is great! If you are required for an exam to do it by hand, then you will have a very special polynomial, where you don't have to compute too much.

Comment: this is something really special about your polynomial: its roots satisfy $a^5=f(a):=-1-1/a$ and you can notice that $f(f(f(t)))=t$ and so every root of your polynomial gives (at most) a cubic extension

Comment: @DietrichBurde That's useful to know, but the exercise is intended to be done by hand. The book has separate exercises to be done with a computer.

Comment: I am not really convinced that applying "tricks" is so desirable. If it is a homework, I wouldn't be concerned to use the known list of cubic polynomials. For certain polynomials, you can apply a "trick", but in general it is not possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The observation made by user8268 is the key to the following paper and pencil factorization. Not ruling out the existence of other possibilities — that trick simply works like charm.

---

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $p(x)=x^6+x+1$ in some extension field of $\Bbb{F}_5$. By Galois theory it follows that
$$
\alpha^5=\frac{\alpha^6}{\alpha}=-\frac{\alpha+1}{\alpha}=-1-1/\alpha  
$$
is another root. The projective linear trasformation (aka a Möbius transformation)
$$f(t)=-1-1/t$$
is "famous" for having order three. Meaning that its third iterate is the identity:
$f(f(f(t)))=t$. It follows that the Frobenius automorphism $\alpha\mapsto \alpha^5$ cycles back to $\alpha$ after three rounds. Therefore the minimum polynomial of $\alpha$ is (a factor of)
$$
m(x)=(x-\alpha)(x-f(\alpha))(x-f(f(\alpha)))=(x-\alpha)(x+1+\frac1\alpha)(x+\frac1{1+\alpha}).
$$
Here I used the fact that $f(f(t))=-1/(1+t)$.

Expanding $m(x)$ gives
$$
m(x)=x^3+Ax^2+Bx-1,
$$
where $A=(1+3\alpha-\alpha^3)/(\alpha+\alpha^2)$ and $B=(1-3\alpha^2-\alpha^3)/(\alpha+\alpha^2).$

How does this help the factorization? The key is that, upon inspection, we see that $A-B=3$. This narrows down the family of putative factors to those of the form
$$
x^3+Ax^2+(A-3)x-1.
$$

All of the above, together with the OPs observation that the polynomial has no roots in $\Bbb{F}_5$, implies that we are looking for a factorization of the form
$$
x^6+x+1=(x^3+Ax^2+(A-3)x-1)(x^3+Cx^2+(C-3)x-1)\qquad(*)
$$
with $A,C\in\Bbb{F}_5$. Looking at the terms of degree five (or the linear terms) on the R.H.S. of $(*)$ tells us that $A+C=0$, so $C=-A$. Expanding further, and looking at the quadratic terms we get the equation
$$
0=-A+(A-3)(C-3)-C=AC-4(A+C)+9=AC-1=-A^2-1.
$$
This has two solutions $A=\pm2$ in $\Bbb{F}_5$. It is straight forward to check that this gives the desired factorization.

---

The same observation allows us to factor for example $g(x)=x^8+x+1$ in $\Bbb{F}_7[x]$. Testing shows that $g(2)=0=g(4)$. The above process, this time starting from $\alpha^7=f(\alpha)$, leads to a full factorization
$$g(x)=(x-2)(x-4)(x^3-3x-1)(x^3-x^2+3x-1).$$
We see the same difference of three in the coefficients of the quadratic and linear terms of the two cubic factors.

See [this older question and its answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1321580/11619) for an earlier incarnation of this projective linear transformation in this context. There was no need to identify the cubic factors there. I only posted this because I had never noticed that difference of three. Undoubtedly that is a known fact given that this particular Möbius transformation appears regularly.

Comment: Galois theory of rational function fields does imply that the coefficients of $m(x)\in F(\alpha)[x]$, in the case where $\alpha$ is transcendental over a base field $F$, belong to a subfield $K\subset F(\alpha)$ such that $F(\alpha)/K$ is a cyclic Galois extension. By Lüroth we know that $K=F(\beta)$ for some $\beta$ (also transcendental over $F$). Thus it was obvious that there would be relation between the coefficients of $m(x)$. I don't recall ever realizing exactly how simple the relation is :-)

Comment: +1 for a beautiful solution (and also because of being glad that my little observation could be used to actually solve the problem :)

Comment: @user8268 Thanks. I feel a bit bad for stealing your well deserved starring role. I wasn't sure whether you want to post something about this, and decided to do it in the end. I have been criticized for posting "answers in the comments".

Comment: no worries in this case; answering in the comments is certainly criminal, but this time I just suggested where one might look

Comment: So two of the irreducible cubics factor $x^5=f(x)$, and the other two $x^5 = f\circ f(x)$ ?   I think I understood the solution, and it is lovely!

Answer (score 3):

My approach is almost certainly not what the author had in mind, but this technique seems quite effective:

If $\alpha$ is a root of a cubic factor in some extension, then by Vieta the constant term of the cubic factor is $- \alpha \cdot \alpha^5 \cdot \alpha^{25} = -\alpha^{31}.$

So compute $x^{31}$ modulo $x^6+x+1$ in $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$:
$$\begin{align*}
x^6 &\equiv -x - 1\\
x^{30} &\equiv -x^5 -1 \\
x^{31} &\equiv -x^6 - x \\
&\equiv 1,
\end{align*}$$

This means $-\alpha^{31} = -1$ for every root $\alpha$ of $x^6+x+1$, so both cubic factors have constant term $-1$. (This computation also rules out the possibility of quadratic or linear factors: all such factors divide $x^{25}-x$, and only $x-1$ divides both $x^{25}-x$ and $x^{31}-1$.)

So each cubic factor looks like $x^3 + xL(x) -1$, where $L(x)$ is a degree $1$ polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$.

This means we are looking for linear polynomials $L_1(x)$ and $L_2(x)$ such that
$$
\begin{align*}
x^6 + x + 1 &= (x^3 + x\,L_1(x) - 1)\cdot (x^3 + x\,L_2(x)-1) \\
&= (x^3-1)^2 + x(x^3-1)\cdot(L_1(x)+L_2(x)) + x^2\cdot L_1(x)L_2(x).
\end{align*}
$$
It's worth noting that a decomposition of the form
$$ (x^3-1)^2 + x(x^3-1)\cdot \text{ linear } + x^2 \cdot \text{ quadratic }$$
is unique, as the linear term can be determined from the $x^5$ and $x^1$ coefficients, and then the quadratic factor can be solved for. Here we have
$$x^6 + x + 1 = (x^3-1)^2 + x(x^3-1)\cdot (-1) + x^2\cdot(x^2+2x)$$
so
$$
\begin{align*}
L_1(x) + L_2(x) &= -1 \\
L_1(x) \cdot L_2(x) &= x^2 + 2x
\end{align*}
$$
and we can use (for example) the quadratic formula to find $L_1$ and $L_2$:
$$
\begin{align*}
L_1(x), \; L_2(x) &= \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{-4x^2-8x+1}}{2} \\
&= \frac{-1\pm\sqrt{x^2+2x+1}}{2} \qquad \text{ (reminder: coefficients are in $\mathbb{F}_5$)} \\
&= -2x, \; 2x-1.
\end{align*}
$$
So $x^6+x+1 = (x^3-2x^2-1)(x^3+2x^2-x-1)$ in $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$.